# How can I load a .csv file in java code to test with weka?

Tags: java, csv, weka

I have a model obtained from `weka` classifier and I want to test it in java code, But when I read instances, an error appear:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: keyword @relation expected, read Token[Word], line 1
at weka.core.Instances.errms(Instances.java:1863)
at weka.core.Instances.readHeader(Instances.java:1740)
at weka.core.Instances.<init>(Instances.java:119)
at licenta1.LoadModelWeka.main(LoadModelWeka.java:18)
```

My code is:

```
package licenta1;

import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;

import java.util.Random;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader ;

public class LoadModelWeka
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   // training
      BufferedReader reader = null;
      reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\Licenta\\BioArtLicTrainSetTask1.csv"));
      Instances train =new Instances (reader);
      train.setClassIndex(0);     
      reader.close();

      NaiveBayes nb = new NaiveBayes();
      nb.buildClassifier(train);
      Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
      eval.crossValidateModel(nb, train, 10 , new Random(1));

      System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\n Results \n=====\n",true));
      System.out.println(eval.fMeasure(1)+" "+eval.precision(1)+" "+eval.recall(1)+" ");           
   }   
}
```

Can somebody help me?
Mt training set is in `.csv` format

Comment: I think that error is because you have closed the `BufferedReader` too soon, the `reader` may be referenced in the `train`, when the `NaiveBayes` using `train` to read data then the `reader` is already closed. Let's try to move the `reader.close()` to the end of function

Answer (score 2):

This snippet is useful to directly load csv content and convert them to Instances. Usually .arff is used for weka operations and this loader directly converts csv files to arff internally and then to Instances class.

```
 CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
 loader.setSource(new File("filename.csv"));
 Instances trainingDataSet = loader.getDataSet();
```

Comment: Make sure file is in classpath or you may need to explicitly specify full path

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks @leopal for the input. This snippet is useful to directly load csv content to Instances. Usually .arff is used for weka operations and this loader directly converts csv files to arff internally. Hope this is brief :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Buffered Reader you can try

```
DataSource source = new DataSource("/some/where/data.arff");
```

For more information visit this link http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code

Comment: The wikispaces wiki was decomissioned and the article is now available from here: https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/use_weka_in_your_java_code/

Answer (score 1):

im using weka jar 3.7.10, and this is how i can load csv using weka :

```js
   DataSource source1 = new DataSource("D:\\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\Licenta\\BioArtLicTrainSetTask1.csv");
        Instances pred_test = source1.getDataSet();
```